# How to program Google Tag Manager for main site and ecommerce subdomain without self-referrals?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a main site (www.oursite.com) and our ecommerce subdomain (shop.oursite.com). In GTM I have set up two tags: 1) a GA Pageview tag which records pageviews on all pages of both sites and 2) a Universal Analytics - Transaction tag which handles the ecommerce transaction info. Both tags I set up with "cookieDomain" set to "auto", in order to avoid self-referrals.

We are correctly recording both pageviews and ecommerce transactions. However, when I look at Google Analytics, I'm still seeing our main site show up as the top referral domain, both for traffic and for transactions.

I've also added the following domains to the Google Analytics Referral Exclusion List: oursite.com, www.oursite.com, shop.oursite.com   And yet a good 27% of the referrals in Google Analytics are from oursite.com.

How do I stop the self-referrals?

Comment: Did you add the domains to the referral exclusion list only recently ? If so recurring visitors might still be attributed to their original source (i.e. the self referral, although admittedly 27% sounds execessive for that scenario). Try and select a timeframe only after the date you've added the domains.

Comment: I added the domains over a week ago - still getting the self-referrals (check first thing this morning had 81% of referral traffic coming from our domain) :(

Answer (score 2):

Try to set up "cookieDomain" to "oursite.com".
In my case, it solved the self-referral and subdomain referral issue.

For some reason, it appears that the "auto" setting didn't work the way Simo Ahava is describing (http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/cross-domain-tracking-across-subdomains/).

Note that I also added "oursite.com" to the GA Property's Referral Exclusion List before changing the cookieDomain, and it didn't seem to have an effect. But I kept it by precaution, despite the clear statement on GA Help Center:

> Google Analytics automatically excludes the domain associated with a property as a referral source, so you won’t see self-referrals in your Analytics reports.

(https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure GA code is fired site wide (including - shop sub domain) in GTM.

I guess main GA code (pageview) is missing at some point before -Transaction Completion causing the self referrals.

Comment: Even if a session restarts that should not count as self referral if the domain is in the referral exclusion list (should be attributed to the last known traffic source or to direct, this is after all the point of the list).